# Is there a way to view the status of a Durable Function Sub Orchestration?

Tags: azure-functions, orchestration, azure-durable-functions

I'm trying to find a way to view the status of a sub orchestration using statusQueryGetUri.

Currently I can only see the custom status which was set when invoking the sub orchestration but would like to be able to see the status of the activities within the sub orchestration as well.

Possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways in which you can retrieve the status of the orchestrations.

1. Azure Function core tools - Example

`func durable get-instances --created-after 2019-09-7T13:57:31Z --created-before  2019-09-10T23:59Z --top 15`

More Info : [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-instance-management#azure-functions-core-tools-1)

Another way is using this API (for func V2 runtime )

```
GET /runtime/webhooks/durableTask/instances?
taskHub={taskHub}
&connection={connectionName}
&code={systemKey}
&createdTimeFrom={timestamp}
&createdTimeTo={timestamp}
&runtimeStatus={runtimeStatus1,runtimeStatus2,...}
&showInput=[true|false]
&top={integer}
```

2. More information on HTTP API - [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-http-api#get-all-instances-status)

Answer (score 0):

[Durable Functions Monitor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DurableFunctionsMonitor.durablefunctionsmonitor) now natively supports navigating to suborchestrations from your parent orchestration's **Details** page (those links are clickable):

[image]
[image]